# w3wp.exe at 60% after 5 minutes right after App_Pool recycle

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, iis

I have IIS running on Windows 2003

I have process w3wp.exe running at 50-80% CPU. After running iisapp.vbs i found out that process is connected to AppPoolX where single web application named X running.

I did recycle this AppPool and the process remained for some time until i did end process tree via Windows Task Manager while new process for this AppPool was created.

I have screenshot of PerfMon running on this AppPool[image] or direct [link here](http://i32.tinypic.com/30veluw.png)

I did checked IIS logs and seen no attacks or whatsoever, all pages requested normally. If you need other info do not hesitate to ask because i really need help!!!

Where do i start debugging or looking for the problem. 90% identical web site is running smoothly at below 5% CPU at max while it has five times less users.

Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the issue with server. It seems to be issue with coding of the site. You need to contact the developer to look for the loophole in the coding, which is causing to spike the CPU load.